# Media Queries not firing (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have an issue where any media query does not work in an Angular component. Non-query based styles however, are applying:

`auth-page.component.html`

```html
<div class="layout-container">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

`auth-page.component.scss`

```css
@import './../../styles/layout';
```

`_layout.scss`

```css
@import './mixins';
@import './variables';

.layout-container {
    padding : 12px;
}

@media only screen and (min-witdh: 100px) {
    .layout-container {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

I've included the viewport tags on my index.html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The normal padding is applied, I've tried absolutely everything I can think of. I've nested the query, nested the class inside the query... Everything.

I've been using Angular for years and I've never once come across this issue. I'm at a complete loss, I'd expect CSS to not work at all, not only part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spelling: min-witdh.

And another thing. Whenever you import something into an angular local component scss. You duplicated the global code into it. You should never import a global scss into the local because if the global scss grows the app code could grow a lot. But if you don’t import the global file you will end up duplicating rules. So I have reached the conclusion that one should avoid the local component scss that angular provides. Instead devide the global scss to separate files and import them only once globally.

Comment: It's going to be one of those days  Happy Derpday! 

Also thanks for the advice! Luckily this project is right at the beginning phase so it should take 2 mins to refactor this.

Comment: The import is a tricky one because all basic angular examples use it. But I does not work well in big apps. I also have my doubts about how it works with themeing. I’m pretty sure that I’m on to something. Ex: angular-bootstrap is a very well used angular library. But it does not include any style. You need to import plain bootstrap a well. I think that a component should not include its style